# R List of lists to dataframe with list name as extra column

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a list of lists that have names.

I want to add them all together into a dataframe but keep all the columns

```
past_earnings_lists[1]
```

successfully returns one list from the list of lists

```
names(past_earnings_lists)[1]
```

successfully returns the name of the list

```
past_earnings <- melt(past_earnings_lists)
```

puts all the data in one data frame but doesn't keep structure

```
past_earnings <- as.data.frame.matrix(past_earnings_lists$ADBE)
```

Successfully takes one list and keeps the structure but doesn't add the name of the list to the dataframe.

For example, adbe has 7 columns and 30 rows; I want it to add an 8th column with the name, adbe, and append it to a dataframe with all the other lists doing the same.

[image: structure]

```
I want a dataframe with the results being:
  sym  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7
1 adbe  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
2 adbe  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
3 air   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
4 air   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
5 alog  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
and so on
```

Comment: this isn't going to fly without a reproducible example

Comment: Agreed that its unlikely you will find help without providing data structure to make it a reproducible example, but you may find the `bind_rows` function from `dplyr` helpful using the `.id` parameter to concatenate your lists while generating a new variable identifying the name of the list. http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html

Comment: there, i've added a screenshot

Comment: It's still not clear. Do you have a list, or a list of lists? Can you include the output of `str` or `dput` of `past_earnings_list`?

Comment: Also note that doing `mylist[1]` returns a *sublist*, whereas `mylist[[1]]` returns the element itself (see the double brackets).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This might work

```
library(purrr)
ans <- map_df(past_earnings_lists, ~as.data.frame(.x), .id="id")
```

It uses `map_df`, which will map over lists and convert the result to data frames (if possible). Use the `.id` argument to add `names` to each data frame as a column.

Comment: That's great:)! How can I revert this one though?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

as @dshkol commented, the easiest is to use `dplyr::bind_rows`:

```
d = data.frame(letter = LETTERS, number = 1:26)
d.list = list(d1 = d, d2 = d)
d.all = dplyr::bind_rows(d.list, .id = "variable")
```

You can also do this in base R with `rbind` and `do.call`:

```
d.all = do.call(rbind, d.list)
```

However, this will not give you a column containing the list names. You could parse it from the `row.names` though:

```
d.all["variable"] = unlist(lapply(
  strsplit(row.names(d.all), ".", fixed = TRUE), function(x) x[[1]])
)
```

Alternatively, loop through your data frames frames and add the label manually prior to binding:

```
for (n in names(d.list))
  d.list[[n]]['name'] = n
d.all = do.call(rbind, d.list)
```

However, it looks like your data frames **don't have column names**. I think you'll need to fix that for either solution to work.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working, added more information on what output i would like

Answer (score 2):

@mikeck was in right track. Splitting string using `.` is tricky as `.` regex matches any character. So we need escape character `\` before the `.`. For anyone who wants to accomplish this with base R, you may try this:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, list)
df$listname <- lapply(strsplit(row.names(df), "\\."), '[[', 1)
```